# How to integrate noVNC client in django project?

Tags: python, django, docker, vnc, vnc-server

Sorry for asking this question directly without showing any effort. I googled a lot but not getting any clue to integrate this. I have to integrate noVNC client to get the screen of docker container. and also do more stuffs on the same page. Please share tutorial for doing the same or guide me in doing this.

Answer (score 2):

You can find 10 examples of various images with noVNC on the Docker Hub, see https://registry.hub.docker.com/search?q=novnc&searchfield= that should give you a clue